# live streamming using ffmpeg for more than stream on the same time

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming

I'm using this command to stream video in ffmpeg but when I stream more than 3 or 4 streams at the same time interruption happen although the process in my device doesn't exceed 50%
I tried to use ffmpeg lib for each stream but interruption still happened

this is my command :

```
 ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -i logo.png -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vb 2000000 -g 60 
-vprofile main -acodec aac -ab 128000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb 
-strict experimental -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=0:0" 
-pass 1 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

Comment: If you're transcoding then you will run into CPU usage issues...

Comment: my cpu doesn't exceed 50% while transcoding and streamming

Comment: try reducing the number of threads for each command using `-threads #`